# Connect to SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to this, and i don't understand how to do it, so i went through this tutorial here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/02/18/step-by-step-installing-sql-server-management-studio-2008-express-after-visual-studio-2010.aspx

And i installed everything i needed.

The point is when i get to the login form, i choose:

**Windows Authentication**
So it means i don't need to enter data. My problem is with the server name which by default is: **(local)**.

I tried to do like this:

Go to SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Services > In Right Side window show all the servers which may stop. If you are using "SQLEXPRESS" then , Right click on SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) and start. After try to connect server... I had same problem but I resolved by these steps.

But there was nothing under SQL Server Services. Someone please help me with this..

Thanks

Comment: You installed an `Express` instance of SQL Server? If so, did you go to the `services.msc` console and actually *Start* the service? It's named `SQL Server ({instance name})`.

Comment: Is it possible you only installed Management Studio?

Comment: I just followed those steps, so it might be that i installed only the Management Studio...

Comment: Are you trying to connect to `LOCAL` or `REMOTE` server? If you installed SQL Server it would have automatically created new SQL Server instance, if you just want to connect to `REMOTE` server just specify that server name.

Comment: i FOUND THIS IN THE CONSOLE . SQL Server VSS Write

Comment: SaUce sorry, i've only used XAMPP and MySQL before, so, i just have this windows 7 lap top and continued with the installation following the steps above. So, i really don't know

Comment: Usually when you install Visual Studio it will give you option to install SQL Server Express.

Comment: You can download and install SQL Server 2012 express from following link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Comment: There are a few files to download when i click on that, which one should i download? i have a x64

Comment: @SaUce [this link is much, much, much better](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579) - it is Express with Service Pack 1, and includes a version of Management Studio that is fully functional (unlike 2012 RTM and earlier, where Management Studio Express was crippled).

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand. Now back to OP issue, you want to download SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe _Express with Tools (SQLEXPRWT)
This package contains everything needed to install and configure SQL Server as a database server including the full version of SQL Server 2012 Management Studio with SP1. Choose either LocalDB or Express depending on your needs above._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've only installed the client tools, so there is no local database engine to connect to. That tutorial assumed you had already installed SQL Server Express as part of Visual Studio setup.

You should uninstall the version of Management Studio you have now, IMHO. Then you need to download `SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe` from this link:

- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351

Run the installer, and on the feature selection screen, make sure you choose Database Engine Services as well as Management Tools - Complete. On the instance configuration screen, it should be pre-selected to `SQLEXPRESS`. On the database engine configuration screen, you want to make sure you have mixed authentication, enter a secure password for the sa account, and add your current user to the list of administrators. These steps will help prevent you from getting locked out of the instance if you log on as a different user or you forget the sa password.

(Sorry if I am remembering those screens out of order.)